# Inserting char variables into table oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've a table `CMP` with two fields as `CMP_CODE varchar2(20)`  and `CMP_NAME varchar2(50)`.

When I'm trying to insert an entry like '`001`' to `CMP_CODE`, every time it is getting inserted as '1'.
My statement was like 
 `Insert into CMP(CMP_CODE ,CMP_NAME) values ('007','test');`
Previously the problem was not there, but I've re-installed our XE database recently, is the problem with that?

Your valuable help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You state you want to insert '001' yet your insert statement has '007' as the value. Please show your real code, not made up code.

Comment: Hi Sam, Sorry for the issue. My Statement is " Insert into CMP(CMP_CODE ,CMP_NAME) values ('007','test'); ". When I try this, value getting inserting is "7", not "007"

Comment: What do you get when you issue `Insert into CMP(CMP_CODE ,CMP_NAME) values ('A007','test');`?

Comment: Hi Barbaros, That statement works fine. Inserted as 'A007'.
Also I've tried as " Insert into CMP(CMP_CODE ,CMP_NAME) values (:CMP_CODE ,:CMP_NAME); " Then passed the values dynamically as A007 & TEST.
It also worked fine. But in this statement also if give CMP_CODE as 007, getting inserted as 7. Thank You.

Comment: Hi Aravind.  Well, have you ever checked if there is an INSERT trigger that probably causing the issue ?

Comment: Hi Barbaros, There is no trigger in the table. I've dropped and created the table again with same columns and data types with sizes 100 and 200 each with cmp_code as Primary Key. Now the first statement where we passes the values in static works fine, but when try to pass values dynamically in statement " Insert into CMP(CMP_CODE ,CMP_NAME) values (:cmp_code,:cmp_name); " and passed '007' and 'test', again inserting as '7' and 'test'. Thank You

Comment: Also for select query like " select * from cmp where cmp_code = :Cmp; " and when pass cmp_code as "007"(Inserted manually an entry '007', 'test' in table), this also not working, but statement like " select * from cmp where cmp_code = '007'; " works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The fieldtype "VARCHAR2" itself is probably NOT responsible for snipping of your zeros.

The error seems to be in your application. In case, if you use an Numeric-Variable-Type (eg. Integer, Long, Float, Decimal) this behavior is very basic and in most cases desirable.

But due very less information about your situation it is kind of hard, to tell whats is really going on.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank You. My situation is I've an application based on C# .net. From my application, for inserting to database the query working is " Insert into cmp(cmp_code ,cmp_name) values (:cmpcode ,:cmpname); " . Then passing the values dynamically '007' for :cmpcode and 'test' for :cmpname. But the data getting inserted to database as '7' & 'test'.

Comment: Tell, what kind of variable-type are you using? In case of "int" for :cmpcode c# snips of your zeros. As i mentioned, this behavior would be very basic.

Use variable-type string instead.